# Change week day index in time

Tags: javascript, date, time

I want to set **week day** index (not month day) in time

for example:

`"2021-11-`**01**`T10:50:02+04:00"` should be converted to `"2021-11-`**08**`T10:50:02+04:00"`

`"2021-11-`**02**`T10:50:02+04:00"` should be converted to `"2021-11-`**08**`T10:50:02+04:00"`

and so on

basically my task is to convert any week day to friday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So update `myDate` to Friday (in current week), you could do something like this:

```
var dayToSet = 5; // Friday
var currentDay = myDate.getDay();
var distance = dayToSet - currentDay;
myDate.setDate(myDate.getDate() + distance);
```

Comment: Noting that this assumes that the week starts on Sunday. It may also start on Monday, Friday or Saturday depending on local rules.